# Marriage after divorce

Tags: hadith, nikah

Salam Alaykum, I was married and I had both a nikkah and a civil wedding in 2019. Unfortunately due to personal reasons we got a divorce in shariah court to anunul the Islamic marrriage in 2020. But due financial issues on my side I was unable to file for divorce in civil court. I have gotten a lawyer now and is filling the civil divorce in a civil court but my ex is refusing to cooperate, which is causing the process to take longer than expected. Now it’s two years and am ready to move on. I have found someone I love and loves me back dearly and is ready to marry me. Can I have a nikkah with my new man now and then complete the civil divorce case later or do I have to wait till I am granted divorce by the civil court as well before entering a new marriage islamically.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the website. Please ask your question again without the huge amount of information. Just ask the question and show only what’s necessary to probably have some more answers.

Comment: If a talaq happened at 2020 you can get marrierd, but your question may have legal implications in the country you live at of which we don't know of because you didn't share the information, for example you couldn't get married simply because divorce is not official and you are committing polygamy....